# Is it possible to create a 0 intercept ridge regression model?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, nonlinear-regression, ridge-regression, variance-inflation-factor

I am working on implementing ridge regression for market mix modeling where I wish to use my own create base(UCM) instead of intercept, I had been using linear regression for this purpose but now my IVs are showing high VIF and as per my business logic, I can't drop these so want to go for ridge regression instead.

Also, is it possible to look at VIF of a ridge model?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How do you see ridge regression helping you?

Comment: @Dave I am using ridge regression because I want to handle high VIF of my independent variables which I cannot drop from the model.

Comment: Why does it affect your work of the VIF is high?

Comment: It makes my estimates less reliable?

Comment: What problem does that cause that ridge regression solves?

Comment: ridge regression can solve multicollinearity, can you suggest anything else?